# Why is viewDidLoad run before didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionViewDataSource` & `UICollectionViewDelegate` in my personal ViewController subclass file. I can now click on the cell in CollectionView and navigate to the child ViewController I want, but the target's `viewDidLoad` method is always run before the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, so I can't get the selected cell's info before the view comes out, for example to get the label name of the selected cell.

Below is the codes I did for now, line 2 is always comes before line 1, but I need to get line 1 first, any ideas?

in UICollectionView's ViewController with datasource and delegate:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("1")  //line 1
}
```

in target's ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("2")  //line 2
}
```

P.S: push segue is using from main to target.

Comment: Have you implemented `prepareForSegue:sender:` in the collection view's controller?

Comment: I had `prepareForSegue` but nothing inside, any statement is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Use `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareForSender:segue:` instead of `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`. The `sender` is the cell that was tapped. If you need its index path, you can get it from the collection view using `indexPathForCell:` (passing the `sender` as the argument).

Comment: Thanks! But I try replace `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` with `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` and I can get what I want! And I found out that `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` run before `prepareForSender`, is anything wrong if I use `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` instead of `prepareForSender `?